# How to add temporary field for "Reenter-Password" for TYPO3 Extensions?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-8.x

in my FE-User-Registration Extension i want to add a 2nd Password-Field, just for checking the spelling of the first password entered.

I don't like to add an extra field for this in the database, because it's only for first entering the password and changing the password purpose.

If the normal password-field and the reenter-password-field are the same, it should be stored in the database. (I also make a salted password here, but it's not important for the issue.)

## I tried the following

```
<label for="reenter_password" class="reenter_password">
    Reenter Password*
</label><br>
<f:form.password id="reenter_password"/>
```

This makes no errors, but i don't get the value.

---

```
<label for="reenter_password" class="reenter_password">
    Reenter Password*
</label><br>
<f:form.password property="reenter_password" id="reenter_password"/>
```

This makes the following Error:

> Exception while property mapping at property path "": Property "reenter_password" was not found in target object of type "RM\Rmregistration\Domain\Model\User"

I know if i make an extra field called reenter_password in my Model, SQL, it would work, but like I said above **I don't want to store this to the database**.

## Is there any way to get the value, and checks it, without storing it to the database with Fluid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put your input like this in your fluid template :

`<input id="reenter_password" type="password" name="reenter_password">`

And see what you've got in `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_POST()` in your controller action.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've added `name` attribute like @MathiasBrodala said.

Comment: It works, but is there a way in fluid to do this or an "API-Way"?

Comment: I changed your input field to `<f:form.password name="reenter_password" id="reenter_password"/>` and now the Value is in `$this->request->getArguments()['reenter_password']` API-conform ;). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an `AbstractValueObject` and validate this one, then, in your update action, take one of the values of the `AbstractValueObject` and set it in your entity.

Comment: How can i use this please?